# Custom tabs with glitches

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to craft fancy looking tabs using angular and its bootstrap component - ui.bootstrap.tabs from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. So far it looks like this:

[image: Tabs with glitches]

Notice glitches in red circles. They are not always there, only appear when browser window is resized to a particularly unhappy size.

The styling is as following:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0 .2em 1em;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 2em;
    background: white;
    border-left: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-top: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.3em;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    margin: 0px 3.2em 0px 0px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.1em;
    right: -2em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    background: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-right: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.1em;
    right: -3em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    background: white;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
    transform:  skew(20deg, 0deg);
    border-left: none;
    border-top: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-right: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: white;
    border-left: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-top: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #b0b7bb;
    border-right: none;
    background: #0066cc;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a:before {
    background: #0066cc;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a:after {
    background: #0066cc;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tab-content {

}
```

Full plunk is here http://plnkr.co/edit/FViETgumIqWCWzQjo8Ff?p=preview .

The question is how to get rid of these glitches. Any help is highly appreciated.

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

Its your `transform:  skew(20deg, 0deg);` on the `.nav-tabs > li > a:after`  I understand that you are trying to achieve a 'slanted' effect, but the skew is skewing by 20degs after the element per the css rules.

MDN suggests not using it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew

You may want to try this alternative technique.
http://lea.verou.me/2013/10/slanted-tabs-with-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: Thank you for prompt response! I changed to skewX as suggested by MDN but glitches are still there. And skew degree is quite ok, I just want the outlines to be straight.

Comment: Maybe z-index the tabs beneath the container on top?  I looked at your plunk.  Basically skew and skewX are working as expected.  They rotate an element regardless of boxmodel, and you've either got to try a different approach for the tab angles, or hide the overflow on the li.

Comment: This ought to be able to achieve the effect you want without any transforms-
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css--net-20763

Comment: Thanks for the links! The last one (tutsplus) doesn't seem to be a good approach as it uses borders to draw slanted tabs and it makes using borders for its original purpose impossible.

Comment: And the one to ea.verou.me helped me better understand transofrms and simplified my code. 
But the glitches are still there. And they also appear in Lea Verou's sample although not so often. The only thing which comes to mind is different fonts used to size borders and transforms when using em. Changed to rem and px, glitches become less acute but still visible.